# Binding domain object to GUI

Tags: swing, model-view-controller, beans-binding

I would like to know how to bind my domain object with are POJOs to my GUI component.  Should I inject my domain object to the constructor of my view, or is there a better design?  Does my domain object have to extend a specific class?

Comment: What GUI component are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Model-View-Controller architecture](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-1998/jw-04-howto.html) and think of you domain object as a model. Binding usually happens in Controller. To simplify it - use a framework such as [Better Beans Binding](http://kenai.com/projects/betterbeansbinding/pages/Home)